Why it will call destructor twice when overloaded assignment operator?
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std; 

class Boom{
    private:
        int no;
    public:
        Boom():no(10){
            //cout << "Create Boom 1..." << endl;
        }
        Boom(int a):no(a)
        {

            //cout << "Create Boom 2..." << endl;
        };
        ~Boom(){
            //cout << "Destructing.." << " " << no << endl;
        };
};

class BoomPoiner {
    private:
        Boom* obj;
        int no;
    public:
        BoomPoiner(int a): no(a){
            cout << "Create pointer... " << this << endl;
        }
        BoomPoiner(BoomPoiner& value){
            cout << "Copy constructor... " << this << endl;
            cout << "Copy constructor...value " << &value << endl;
            this->obj = value.obj;
            this->no = value.no;
            value.no = 5;
        }
        BoomPoiner operator=(Boom *obj){
            this->obj = obj;
            cout << "= operator... " << this << endl;
            return *this;
        }
        ~BoomPoiner(){
            cout << "Delete pointer obj... " << this << " " << no << endl;
            delete obj;
        }
};

void makePointer(){
    //std::unique_ptr<Boom> boom = std::make_unique<Boom>(1);
    //Boom* boom2 = new Boom(2);
    Boom* boom = new Boom();
    BoomPoiner ptr(1);
    ptr = boom;
    cout << "out func" << endl;
    return;
}


int main(){
    makePointer();
    return 0;
}

When I tried to do something like above, it will keep call the destructor of BoomPointer. I only have created one BoomPointer instance and one Boom instance. Theoretically, it should call only once for the destructor.
The result:
Create pointer... 0x16fdff2a8

= operator... 0x16fdff2a8

Copy constructor... 0x16fdff298

Copy constructor...value 0x16fdff2a8

Delete pointer obj... 0x16fdff298 1

out func

Delete pointer obj... 0x16fdff2a8 5

main(85154,0x1eaf39b40) malloc: Double free of object 0x100204100

main(85154,0x1eaf39b40) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in 
malloc_error_break to debug


Rule of three. Also what is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems

Assignment operator should usually take argument by reference(of same class type) not by pointer.

BoomPoiner operator=(Boom *obj) returns a copy that needs to be cleaned up.

BoomPoiner needs to implement the rule of 3, your assignment operator should return a reference. The combination of these two issues results in creating a copy of the object when returning from the assignment operator which is causing your double destruction

@user12002570 there's nothing wrong with defining an assignment operator taking arbitrary types, its simply not a copy assignment operator

@AlanBirtles Yes, it's not "copy" assignment operator but still an assignment operator.

You should be outputting the value of this in your print statements.  If you had done this, you would have seen that the destructor for a particular object is not called twice, and that a temporary object (which you did not write any output for) is being created.

@user12002570 thanks for you ans. I updated my question. More one thing I want to ask. After I added the copy constructor and changed the value of the old object in the copy constructor, I've noticed that the new object was released first? Why?

@MichaelTsai Objects are destroyed in the reverse order of their creation. So if you create two objects then the second one will be destroyed first.

@user12002570 you can see my result, before out of function, the new object (no=1) was destroyed first. Isn't it the new object(no = 1) returned after copy constructor? And then, after out of the function, the old object (no=5) is destroyed.

@MichaelTsai Print also the value of this inside your ctors. For example, inside the copy ctor write cout << "Copy constructor... << this;". Do this for all other ctors and dtors. That will make it clear. Let me know after adding/printing this if you still have the same doubts.

@user12002570 oh, I get it. Thanks very much.

@MichaelTsai You're welcome :)

@user12002570 sorry, I think a more while. I still don't understand. I updated the code. I first created a instance (0x16fdff2a8) and then call the =operator and then call the copy constructor during return. The new instance (0x16fdff298) is assigned from (0x16fdff2a8) but why the new instance(0x16fdff298) will be destroyed immediately, not the old instance (0x16fdff2a8)?

@MichaelTsai Note that you don't need makePointer function at all. Just move the contents that are inside makePointer to main. Second, constructors don't return an object of class type. Also, I print the this in the ctor and dtor of Boom class also. You don't want to miss anything that may be happening. Also, tbh it is not clear what is the exact problem that you're asking about in the modified program. I mean if you use a debugger or proper cout's then it should be clear. Maybe add some more details about what exactly is unclear in your question.

Which output line is unclear? Maybe explain/provide the expected output and current output. That should tell us the problem you're asking about.

@user12002570
BoomPoiner(BoomPoiner& value){ cout << "Copy constructor... " << this << endl; cout << "Copy constructor...value " << &value << endl; this->obj = value.obj; this->no = value.no; value.no = 5;  } 
in this line, I dont understand why the new instance will be released immediately after copy constructor, why not the old instance released?

as you can see, Create pointer... 0x16fdff2a8, I created the instance. and then it called the copy constructor in the operator = overload. Copy constructor... 0x16fdff298. the new one is 0x16fdff298. So I think the old one 0x16fdff2a8 should be destroyed and return the new one 0x16fdff298. But finally it doesn't work like this way... It will destroy the old one 0x16fdff2a8 first

@MichaelTsai Btw you can use two tick marks ` to format your text as code in comments.

@MichaelTsai There seems to be no new instance in BoomPoiner(BoomPoiner& value){ cout << "Copy constructor... " << this << endl; cout << "Copy constructor...value " << &value << endl; this->obj = value.obj; this->no = value.no; value.no = 5; }. Obejct creation and assignment are different things. There is no object creation in above. The question is very unclear. I would highly recommend a good c++ book.

@user12002570 but what is the instance  0x16fdff298? Copy constructor... 0x16fdff298

@MichaelTsai Inside the copy ctor, you're not creating any new object. The only real good way to understand every step of the code is by clearing the basics first like by using a book.

@user12002570 but why their address is different. one is 0x16fdff298, another one is 0x16fdff2a8

@MichaelTsai I see now, The second object is from the return statement return *this. It creates a copy using the copy ctor. Then that object is destroyed first as usual at the end of expression. This is why you see it being destroyed first.

@user12002570 yes, this is the question. Why the second object will be destroyed first? Why won't it return out to replace the old one?

@MichaelTsai When you wrote return *this you're returing a copy which creates a new instance. This instance is destroyed first because it is discarded(no longer needed anymore). This happens at the end of the full expression ptr = boom;.

@user12002570 I really get it this time. thanks very much.

@MichaelTsai You're welcome :)
